# user control in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-controls

I have jquery file (javascript file) and a css.
I would like to "publish" it as a UserControl (like UserControls in asp.net).
This is not plugin because it is html area with functionality and design that I want to duplicate in several pages.
For example - filters panel.

Page 1:

```
<select id="aa"/>
<select id="bb"/>
Javascript file to load aa and bb options
rest of the html for page 1
```

Page2:

```
<select id="aa"/>
<select id="bb"/>
Javascript file to load aa and bb options
rest of the html for page 2
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "can a javascript file in an HTML page be used like an ASP.NET control", the answer is no. You have to consider that HTML pages are inherently static, and they don't build themselves.

Can you use some method to inject a javascript snippet *into* a DOM once the page has started loading? The answer to that is a resounding:

> YES

It just depends on what you're aiming to do. Can you give any more information besides this? Can you give us an idea of the workflow you intend? I think you pretty well have it correct except slightly backwards in your post. Pages1 & 2 would just have regular HTML and then a bit of javascript to include the page right there, or something like jQuery to load a portion from the file right there.